# Can't read html page which opens in Google Chrome in R using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to read html page https://www.101hotels.ru/kazakhstan/alma-ata#page=2 in R using rvest package.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

names_path <- '.item-name a'
webpage <- read_html("https://www.101hotels.ru/kazakhstan/alma-ata#page=2")
names <- html_nodes(webpage, names_path) %>%
         html_text()
names
```

It gives exactly same results as 1st page.
If I put above url in Google Chrome it shows another results, i.e results of 2nd page. What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Web pages are complicated. Browsers are complicated. What you see is often not what you get. You must learn to use the developer tools in your browser to see what is actually there rather than what the browser shows you. http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/Python/PythonWebScrape/PythonWebScrape.html might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a fragment (the part after `#`) and you won't be able to select it with `rvest`. You'll have to use `RSelenium`, or if you're lucky, the data may be present in a script tag on the page or loaded via ajax request.